# Is there any way to version / tag individual components inside a repository?

Tags: git

I'm still pretty new to git, so my question lies somewhere between *"is this even possible?"* and *"where would I even begin to look for the answer to this?"*

I have inherited a code base which is all stored in one git/GitHub repository, and I need to establish a version numbering scheme. I've already determined that the best approach is to use `git tag` and [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) to establish a 3-digit version number like v1.3.4, and also to use the `git describe` command to have extra info on there. And that's all great.

The trouble is that this is really a software package with two different components, and *later on we may need to ship those components individually*. So I'm trying to figure out a good version numbering scheme to handle that, and see if I can make this version numbering scheme work within the git/GitHub infrastructure.

So let's pretend that the overall application is a fishing pole, which has a rod and a reel. What I'd like to do is be able to version all of those individually. So we could have a release:

- FishingPole v1.2.1, consisting of
- FishingRod v1.0.1
- FishingReel v1.2.0

Later on, if we make a change to FishingReel, we bump its revision and naturally bump the top-level revision too, but FishingRod doesn't change:

- FishingPole v1.2.2, consisting of
- FishingRod v1.0.1
- FishingReel v1.2.1

The trouble is that it appears to me that a `git tag` can only apply to the repository as a whole. As a related problem, it seems like there wouldn't be any way to make `git describe` give a description of a component (FishingRod or FishingReel), but rather it would only describe the repository as a whole (it would only describe FishingPole). **Is there any sensible way to make this scheme work with `git tag` and `git describe` if all these pieces exist in the same repository?**

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "apply to a repository as a whole". A tag is associated with one specific commit, and multiple tags can refer to the same commit. More important is that your build system, given the code at a particular commit, can build any of the three release artifacts separately.

Comment: @chepner Yeah I was trying to figure out how to best articulate my question. Using my example above, is there any useful way to use `git tag` and `git describe` to record and read the version of FishingReel only, separate from the rest of the files in the repository? Or do I always need to track the version of "everything" in my tags, e.g. my tag would need to read "FishingPole V1.2.2 FishingRod v1.0.1 FishingReel v1.2.1"?

Comment: You don't need one giant tag. Just use separate tags; if the same commit happens to be `Pole-1.2.2` and `Rod-1.0.1`, then that commit has two tags.

Comment: @chepner Yes, but in that case doesn't `git describe` lose all its usefulness? Because my understanding is that `git describe` refers back to the most recent tag, so if I add a the `Rod-1.0.1` tag and then the `Pole-1.2.2` tag, then `git describe` will always return `Pole-1.1.2-(otherstuff)`, and I would have to go digging by hand to learn about the latest revision of `Rod` and `Reel`... is my understanding correct?

Comment: You can use `--match` to filter the tags you consider "applicable" to the commit under question.

Comment: @chepner Thanks! So if I understand correctly, I could just `git tag` the `Rod`, `Reel`, and `Pole` components as appropriate, and then if I want to get a fully decorated, appropriate version number I can just do that using `git describe --match`. Is that correct? I will of course be more than happy to accept this as the answer if it's submitted as one ;-)